# Is there any simple way to detect if reading STL file is in ASCII or Binary Format?

Tags: wpf, stl, helix-3d-toolkit

How can I found programmatically if reading STL file is in ASCII or Binary format.
I am using C# WPF and Helix Toolkit for loading STL files.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171521/verifying-that-an-stl-file-is-ascii-or-binary

Comment: I already see this answer but it is not quite good for me. I wonder if there is much better way to detect.

Comment: No, there is no 100% bulletproof way to distinguish between binary and ASCII STL files. The linked answer provides the best solution possible.

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet: What does "not quite good for me" mean. What issues do you have with the solution provided in above link? Looks *solid* (pun intended) to me. It's natural to check the first bytes of a document to decide whether it's of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid if you find "solid" word in header (as Ardahan said) insufficient the only remaining way is consistency check or parser. There are several (somehow "stupid") options:

1. ASCII STL file is completely made of characters that can be read by humans with exception of a new line. (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, ., -). So if you find anything except these, it cannot be an ASCII STL (the other way around is not sufficient - e.g. when you find only proper characters, it does not mean it is a valid ASCII STL file - see point 3).
2. You can make consistency check on number of triangles versus size of file (e.g. you expect the file *is* binary and if the consistency check fails, then it's not, or at least not a valid one). Consistency check is : numOfTriangles * sizeof(STLTriangleStructure) + 84 == file size. I'm not sure this is 100% bulletproof - you can be lucky and have proper 4 bytes in ASCII STL at offset 80 so it will correspond to file size, however I think it is a rare case.
3. ASCII STL file may consist only out of predefined set of words (solid, facet, normal, loop, ...) with exception of first line. These words must be in given order - you can write a parser for it, if it fails, then it's not a valid ASCII STL file.